# Android Studio Basic's First Exercise Visualization and HEX Kernel

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I have an AMD E1 Radeon processor and get the following message:

> ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

There are two options:

- Android Documentation (BIOS Option)

Before attempting to use this type of acceleration, you should first determine if your development system’s CPU supports one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:

Intel Virtualization Technology (`VT`, `VT-x`, `vmx`) extensions and 
AMD Virtualization (`AMD-V`, `SVM`) extensions (On Android they are only supported for Linux).
The specifications from the manufacturer of your CPU should indicate if it supports virtualization extensions. If your CPU does not support one of these virtualization technologies, then you cannot use virtual machine acceleration.

Note: Virtualization extensions are typically enabled through your computer's BIOS and are frequently turned off by default. Check the documentation for your system's motherboard to find out how to enable the virtualization extensions.

or

- Genemotion.

I do not have `AMD-V`, `SVM` and `Intel-VTx`. I think that `Genemotion` may be the best fit.

I have also got errors highlighted in the code.

The following code appears:

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
>   Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
>   NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.
>   Or: Automatically add all missing attributes